# streaming h.264 video Using gstreamer

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, gstreamer

I am trying to stream a h265 encoded video using gstreamer. I am using the command

> gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=/home/user/Desktop/sample_mpeg4.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! video/x-h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! deinterlace ! xvimagesink*

i am getting this

> WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link h264parse0 to ffmpegcsp0

what mistake i have to overcome

and why

> ffdec_h264

i couldn't able to find

Getting the error if try this

> gst-launch-0.10 uridecodebin uri=file:///home/user/Desktop/sample_mpeg4.mp4 ! xvimagesink

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0: GStreamer encountered a general stream error.
Additional debug info:
qtdemux.c(3891): gst_qtdemux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I suppose this is a typo :

> I am trying to stream a *h265* video

right ?

Second you should use uridecodebin for that usecase :

```
gst-launch uridecodebin uri=file:///home/user/Desktop/sample_mpeg4.mp4 ! xvimagesink
```

The actual problem with your launch line is that h264parse outputs h264 material (video/x-h264), which still has to be properly decoded into video/x-raw by the decoder of your choice.

Something that should work with 0.10 :

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location= /home/user/Desktop/sample_mpeg4.mp4 ! qtdemux ! ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

decodebin takes care of that for you, so you'll be better off using it.

Comment: @user2732944, do you have something preventing you from using gstreamer 1.0 ? That pipeline works with 1.0 :)

Comment: Other than that, I edited my answer with a "manual" 0.10 pipeline.

Comment: Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0: GStreamer encountered a general stream error.
Additional debug info:
qtdemux.c(3891): gst_qtdemux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0:
streaming stopped, reason not-linked
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline                                                            Giving this error, if try yours prev command

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use playbin2?

```
gst-launch-0.10 playbin2 uri=file:///path/to/your/file.mp4
```

If for some reason you want to use uridecodebin, the problem is that you are getting a 'not-negotiated' error. This means that the data produced by uridecodebin isn't directly accepted by your sink (in this case).

I'd recommending using:

```
gst-launch-0.10 uridecodebin uri=file:///home/user/Desktop/sample_mpeg4.mp4 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink
```

The second ffmpegcolorspace might not be needed. Playbin2 already handles all of this to you.

Comment: ya this is working fine. Can you clear this command. According to me we should use gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=///path ! demux(according to format,for h264 qtdemux) ! ffdec_h264(for decoding h264 input file) ! ffmpegcolourspace ! ximagesink. Then what is uridecodebin and videoscale??? though that command didn't mentioned about format or codec. How it's streaming??

Comment: uridecodebin is an element that does **autoplugging**, meaning that it will identify the type of input and data and will use elements found at your system's plugins to decode the data.

videoscale is capable of scaling video to different dimensions, you might require it if your sink can't handle resizing by itself.

If all you want is playback, playbin2 is the way to go as it will automatically manage the pipeline for decoding/playback for you